# Upgrading r-base from v3.6 to v4.0 Linux

Tags: r, linux, ubuntu, installation

I am trying to install R-base 4.0, but it keeps installing v3.6. I've tried:

```
sudo apt install deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/
sudo apt-get install r-base
```

and v3.6, not 4.0 was installed. Next I tried:

```
sudo apt install deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran40/
sudo apt-get upgrade r-base
```

and it didn't work.

How do I upgrade to Rv4.0? I am using Pop_Os, no Ubuntu. Could that be the issue?

Comment: Playing with `focal-` versus `bionic-` seems to be risky, as I suspect that have different ideas of what basic libraries are available and/or installed. Regardless, adding a repository is one step, have you done `apt-get update` to actually retrieve package information from the new repo? (Read https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/README.html for more detailed instructions.)

Comment: Does this help: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1237102/problem-installing-r-4-0-on-ubuntu-18-04

Answer (score 3):

First off, your initial line is wrong. There is not such `apt install deb` command. You are *supposed to edit the apt sources file by hand* (though these days there may be GUI solutions to it as well).

Second, you omitted to *actually use the new repo* by not running `sudo apt update` (or equally `sudo apt-get update`).  You *must* update the local indices.

Third, a preferred way is to just upgrade as you (almost) did in the second paragraph.  But upgrade takes no package argument!

Fourth, this has nothing to do with Pop!OS as we are talking only about `apt` and `apt-get` here.

For completeness, I did a little blog and video about the R 3.6.* to R 4.0.* upgrade. More info [here](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/blog/2020/04/26/#026_upgrade_to_R400) if you care.

PS Fifth, as r2evans noted in the comment, be sure to pick the right distro.  I run straight Ubuntu so "focal" it is more me. You probably want R 4.0.* from the Ubuntu build matching your Pop!OS build.